# How can I remove Indentation in Newtonsoft JSON and ASP.NET Core and add it into settings

Tags: json, asp.net-core, json.net, formatting

I'm supposed to convert our JSON output into canonical JSON.

My 2 questions are:

1. How do I remove all indentation and whitelines e.g. ?
2. How do I add those settings to `startup.cs` ?

My colleague wrote the methods to create the JSON files with the `JsonWriter` and `JsonReader` methods from Newtonsoft.

I already overwrote the `DefaultContractResolver` in a new class to sort the keys alphabetically, but failed to find a proper point in the startup to add those settings. Also I'm missing the option to remove all indentation, new lines etc.

Here is my `CanonicalContractResolver`:

```
public class CanonicalContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateContract(type);
            
        // remove Intendation here

        return contract;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        return base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization).OrderBy(p => p.PropertyName).ToList();
    }
}
```

The afore mentioned `JsonReader` and `JsonWriter` classes (that need the canonical JSON output)  are linked like this in the `Configure` method in `startup.cs` - and I don't really understand where I should add those changes I made in my `CanonicalContractResolver` class.

```
services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new SignaturesConverter());
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new PolicyConverter());
            });
```

I'm a beginner in software engineer and this is my first post on Stackoverflow. I already researched around 6-7 hours in this topic, but the Newtonsoft documentation is very sparse and hasn't helped me a lot.

Thank you all in advance for helping!

Comment: *My colleague wrote the methods to create the JSON files with the **`JsonWriter`** and `JsonReader` methods from Newtonsoft.* -- then we need to see the `JsonWriter` method.  The writer controls the indentation.  The contract resolver does not.  But you might try setting `options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.None` in `AddNewtonsoftJson()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Format property of `NewtonsoftJson`.

If you set to `Indented`:

```
services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            });
```

Then the output looks like this:

[image]

If you set to `None`:

```
services.AddControllers()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
                    options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.None;
                });
```

Then the output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: +1
Thank you very much, this was just what I was looking for. 

Now I only need to find where to apply the override from the CreateProperties Method, then I'm done.